# Is it possible to set the background of Drawable to a Drawable class name in XML?

Tags: android, drawable, xml-drawable

I found some code in our project where someone is iterating over the children of a `ViewGroup` so they can set a custom Java-based drawable as the background. I'd like to clean that up a bit by setting the background drawable in our layout XML files.

Is there a way to specify a Java class to use as the background via the XML layout definition?

Comment: What do you mean "specify a Java class" as the background? Are you talking about an image from res/drawable? Or some actual java class?

Comment: I have a Java class that extends Drawable (since they wanted to do more with gradients than an XML-drawable allows) that I'd like to use as a background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking around quite a bit I was unable to find a way to do this. I had to specify the background drawable in code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can reference the java class by specifying it's full path (i.e. its package).
For instance, com.example.android.yourClass.